# How can I change a word (that occurs often) in the document all at once

Tags: overleaf, editors

I wanted to know if there is a key combination in Overleaf to change a word that occurs often in the document. Is there a possibility to change it all at once?

For Example

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet **Soerren**, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam **Soerren**. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum **Soerren**
> sit amet.

I try to change **Soerren** into **Sören**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet **Sören**, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam **Sören**. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum **Sören**
> sit amet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press Ctrl+F when you edit your document on Overleaf. This opens the search-and-replace dialogue window at the top right.

[image: Search-and-replace dialogue window highlighted in Overleaf]

To ensure that you only replace "Soeren" and not "Soerensen", press the third button on the bottom of that window (it looks like `"..."`, highlighted in pink in the screenshot). (If you like you can also toggle on case sensitive search with the `Aa` button and/or use regular expressions.)

You can replace all words at once if you then click "All". I'm always a bit careful and go through at least some of the matches to make sure they look OK before I hit the "All" button.

See also [the Overleaf help page about searching and replacing](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_do_I_get_to_the_next_search_match_result,_or_perform_a_search_and_replace%3F) and [the help page about regular expressions](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Can_I_use_regular_expressions_for_%22replace_with%22%3F).